# If value it less then 0 select radio box in an array

Tags: c#, radio-button

Is there a way to select a radio box in an array?

I have the following code:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Part2SummaryAmount) <= 0);
{
    rdoPart2SummaryChoice.Items[2].Selected = true;
}
```

what I want to do is if the Part2SummaryAmount is 0 or less I want to select a radio box.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoPart2SummaryChoice" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="There is enough money to cover your basic living expenses." />
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="" />
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="" />
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Is this the correct way to go about this? I also am not sure on this error:
[image]

Comment: try `Convert.ToDouble` instead

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Do not have a CurrentCuture class. Do I need one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parse that number to a *floating point* type. Because it's not a valid integer.

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(Part2SummaryAmount) <= 0.0)
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. Still no luck ;/

Answer (score 1):

Try converting this number to `double` first and then compare it. Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to parse floating numbers both with `,` and `.`

```
if (Double.Parse(Part2SummaryAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= 0);
{
    rdoPart2SummaryChoice.Items[2].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: I don't have anything with CultureInfo. Do I neeed to add that class?

Comment: @FrankThornton you need to add `using System.Globalization;` to the top of your file